# Render page after onActivate

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

When you take a look at the AngularDart Heroes routing tutorial then you´ll notice that the `hero_component.html` has got an `*ngIf` null-check div around its content. This is required because the `HeroComponent` gets its `id` from the parameters of the current `RouterState` and in order to get access to the `RouterState` you have to implement the `onActivate` hook.

```
  @override
  void onActivate(_, RouterState current) async {
    final id = getId(current.parameters);
    if (id != null) hero = await (_heroService.get(id));
  }
```

The `onActivate` hook gets called after the HTML gets rendered thus the `hero` could be null.

```
<div *ngIf="hero != null">
  <h2>{{hero.name}}</h2>
  <div>
    <label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
  </div>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

This looks like a very ugly piece of code to me because you have to introduce a new DOM node just to null-check a property. Is there any other solution to this problem like delaying the initial page rendering or having `onActivate` called before `ngOnInit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the extra DOM node by using a `<template>` tag, as described here: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/structural-directives#template-to-the-rescue

```
<template [ngIf]="hero != null">
  ...
</template>
```